# how can get vim to support for python without reinstalling it

Tags: python, vim

I need vim to support python interpreter, and run the command `vim --version | grep python`, which prints `-python -python3`, means vim doesn't support python. How can I get vim support python and python3 without reinstalling vim? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: My question is without recompiling vim. Is that possible? @martijn-pieters.

Comment: No, that's not possible. That's what those flags indicate, options that have been compiled in.

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks@MartijnPieters